# Would an underground wizarding school be practical?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

It seems like there would be many advantages to having a magical school underground. First, it might decrease on some security measures that are necessary for Hogwarts such as the extensive Muggle-Repelling charms, the entrance could be set up to look like an old mine which would prevent most Muggles from entering, or there could be a door concealed as a wall that would need a spell to open. Also, if it was underground it could be quite large seeing as there wouldn't be many geological obstructions in the way.

So my questions are:

- Are there any obvious downfalls to this?
- Are there any major downfalls to this?
- And if not why have none of the major wizarding schools considered it?

Comment: Technically this is true for any building that you wouldn't want random people to enter. But then, you know, you have no windows.

Comment: What's wrong with the current Muggle-repellent and unplottable charms? They seem to work fine at the moment.

Comment: `if it was underground it could be quite large seeing as there wouldn't be many geological obstructions in the way` Umm, what? Wouldn't that mean that there are _more_ geological obstructions in the way?

Comment: There's a fair few instances of a tiny building being magically bigger on the inside, who's to say they even need to bother with building underground in the first place?

Comment: How does one play Quidditch underground? :P

Comment: ermm i meant geological obstructions like MOUNTAINS not like rock, and they could enchanct a room to act like a quidditch field like they enchant a room for firenze when he comes to teach

Comment: @padfoot The fact that you meant *mountains* doesn't exactly solve the issue of literally being inside a geological obstruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It theoretically could work - the Ministry of Magic is  underground.

There are no known wizarding schools that are underground, but wizards do have structures where all or a large part of it is underground - the Ministry of Magic is entirely underground.

> “Then he could see nothing at all; he could hear only a dull grinding noise as the telephone box made its way down through the earth. After about a minute, though it felt much longer to Harry, a chink of golden light illuminated his feet and, widening, rose up his body, until it hit him in the face and he had to blink to stop his eyes watering.
>
> ‘The Ministry of Magic wishes you a pleasant day,’ said the woman’s voice.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 7 (The Ministry of Magic)*</sup></sub>

It’s very likely to be considered secure, since it’s where the British wizarding government is located. If underground buildings were known to be unsecure, then they’d likely not have chosen it for the Ministry. With this in mind, there’s no clear reason why it wouldn’t be possible for a wizarding school to be underground.

## It might be that underground isn’t considered good for a school.

St. Mungo’s couldn’t be located underground because it was considered “unhealthy” for a hospital.

> “Wasn’t easy to find a good location for a hospital. Nowhere in Diagon Alley was big enough and we couldn’t have it underground like the Ministry – wouldn’t be healthy.” 
> <sub><sup>* -Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 22 (St Mungo’s Hospital for Magical Maladies and Injuries)*</sup></sub>

It’s possible that it might have also been considered “unhealthy” for a school as well. In addition, certain activities, like Quidditch and flying practice, and Herbology, would be difficult to still have in an entirely underground school. There might not be much space for flying, the plants would need some sort of light (though perhaps there are magical equivalents to grow lamps), which would mean special arrangements would need to be made for those subjects to continue.

## They’re usually in mountainous areas for defense against threats.

Underground certainly isn’t the traditional place for wizarding schools. The Pottermore writing on them states that wizarding schools are usually built in mountainous areas, for ease of defense.

> As a general rule, magical schools tend to be situated in landlocked, mountainous areas (although there are notable exceptions, as will be seen), as such regions are difficult for Muggles to access, and easier to defend from Dark wizards. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Wizarding Schools (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wizarding-schools)*</sup></sub>

Whether mountainous areas would be easier to defend than underground isn’t known, but it would be easier than somewhere that’s not out of the way somehow.